# how to parse a string to DateTime in c#?

Tags: c#, datetime

I want to subtract dt2 (2023-12-31) from dt1 (2023-01-01) in c#, but when i try to debug the codes it says " System.FormatException: 'String '2023-12-31 08:00:00' was not recognized as a valid DateTime.' "
[image: can not recognized as a valid DateTime]
my codes:

```
DateTime dt1 = DateTime.Parse("2023-01-01 08:00:00");
DateTime dt2 = DateTime.Parse("2023-12-31 08:00:00");
TimeSpan diff = dt2.Subtract(dt1);
Console.WriteLine(diff.ToString());
```

How i can fix this error?

Comment: Your question is how to parse a string to DateTime, not how to subtract them. You will find plenty of duplicates on SO if you search.

Comment: Cannot reproduce the error: [Demo](https://dotnetfiddle.net/B76e9h). Have you tried with [`DateTime.ParseExact()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.parseexact?view=net-7.0)?

Comment: Why do you believe your error has anything to do with the subtraction? The error says something different. The line highlighted, indicating the error is on this line, is a different?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your issue is not about subtracting DateTimes but the exception happens when you parse them. The reason is that `DateTime.Parse` uses your current culture's information(like date-separator) when you don't pass another. It seems that you are from iran, so this lets reproduce the exception:

```
System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("fa-IR");
DateTime dt2 = DateTime.Parse("2023-12-31 08:00:00");
```

So one way to fix it is to pass `CultureInfo.InvariantCulture`:

```
DateTime dt1 = DateTime.Parse("2023-01-01 08:00:00", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
DateTime dt2 = DateTime.Parse("2023-12-31 08:00:00", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Comment: It would be good to change the second example to use the same strings as the OP - dashes rather than slashes. (I'd still expect that to work though.)

Comment: @JonSkeet: fixed, copied accidentially a try from linqpad instead of the original code